# Difference in Ambient Data Framework, Context Engine, and Wrapper Features?

Tags: experience-manager, ambient-data-framework

I'm trying to understand the the Context Engine Cartridge and Wrapper features built on ADF. Here's research and questions on how to manage the relationship between claims, device families, and XPM preview features.

- The **[ADF](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-D4EA5B27-3166-4467-AA70-0F47669F784E)** ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) explain
  claims deal with Web server data along with explicit) data from Audience Manager. The specific [default claims are listed as well](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_DA127CED960147D9AFDDF2FD44DDFB28). **Since we can set up additional claims, then this could include any other data an organization has on a given visitor, right?**
- The **[Context Engine Cartridge](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_CEC_10_2013/concept_D33EC02CD232488B85132BD75057B40F)** adds a `Context Map` of property-value pairs as additional claims, specifically aspects for: [Browser](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_CEC_10_2013/reference_D1F3AD71C52542528C1D2F5C4D50D730), [Device](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_CEC_10_2013/reference_FE372665AFE6420080C04574B121ACD2), and [OS](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_CEC_10_2013/reference_FC73E3BE9A7C4E6DAB53C6F5EFA0EBE9).
- The **[Context Engine Cartridge wrapper](https://github.com/NunoLinhares/TridionContextEngineWrapper)** groups devices into families.

Let me know if I misinterpret these relationships. The docs mention [Footprints map to ADF keys](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_68815A46800341DC8B7D9A234D649DBA). **How are *keys* related to claims?**

**Device Preview and the Footprint Questions**

1. **Configure Device Families.** Could I manage these in Tridion and publish to the device family config (any server restarts needed--are changes automatic)?
2. **Device *Features* Instead of Families?** Could a *device family* be focused on a feature? I'd like to collect devices that are (for example) touch-enabled. Would this make sense? `<devicefamily name="touch-enabled">...`
3. For "click trail," is that something I could "fake" with a Footprint (change the footprint to make Staging think I clicked on a set of sites)?

Comment: The ADF link is broken

Comment: I updated the ADF link to the latest version (with the new SDL Live Content URL, after it introduced the that drop-down for versions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll try to answer some of the questions I saw:

> Since we can set up additional claims, then this could include any
>   other data an organization has on a given visitor, right?

Anyone can add any claim to the ADF and it can have pretty much any value. So yeah, go nuts.

> The docs mention Footprints map to ADF keys. How are keys related to
>   claims?

The "keys" would be the URI of claims in the claim store. To phrase it differently, you can link a footprint directly to a claim in the ADF. The idea with footprints is that you can test what your site looks like when certain claims in ADF have a certain value.

> Device Preview and the Footprint Questions

Although there might be functional relationships between claims, footprints, and devices in both Device Preview and the Context Engine -- there is no direct link between them technically. So you'll need to manage the relationships yourself.

> Last one: For "click trail," is that something I could "fake" with a Footprint (change footprint and Staging thinks I clicked on a set of sites)?

I don't know the "click trail" feature you are referring to, but if it's a claim in the ADF: absolutely!

Comment: I removed the details but left the doc links so the question should be clearer. :-) Even with the tl;dr version, you've covered my questions.